# Assigning only the first value in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Given a dynamic list, that has potential to grow, is it possible to order the list such that no matter how it's otherwise sorted, a particular value is first?

```
list = ['bunny','cow','pig','apple','xerox']
list.sort()
```

ex. I want 'cow' to always be first on this list, and the rest can be ordered however. Or even better, 'cow' is always first and then they're alphabetically sorted after following that rule.

Answer (score 4):

Use a key function that orders that value first:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: (0, x) if x == 'cow' else (1, x))
```

This will put `cow` first because `0 < 1` and everything else is sorted lexicographically.

Comment: This works perfectly but I'd suggest writing the key function as `lambda x: (x != cow), x`  (it's like the difference between writing `not foo` and `False if foo else True`).

Comment: While that would work, I don't think the meaning is as obvious (although I admit to using similarly terse constructs in MySQL `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest create a class yourself that always use list[1:] for sort, but returns the appended list[0]+sorted(list[1:]). Or, you can just create an individual parameter to store "cow", like list.First = "cow", list.Rest = ['bunny','pig','apple','xerox']